# How can i find verb on the subordinate clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, subordinate-clauses

> **On their migrations birds sometimes frequent very different environments from those in which they nest**, and a study of the migratory birds alone might be very misleading to one endeavoring to classify birds ecologically.

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: I think the verb here is 'frequent'. Look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: The verb in the relative clause is *nest*.

Comment: from my test ..
"frequent"?..

Comment: Not in phrase of the relative pronoun  :)

Comment: I see several verbs here: "frequent", "nest", "classify".

Comment: wait.. nah .. frequent?
dose it work?

Comment: Folks, the answer to this question is not "Look in a dictionary." It's also not "nest". See StoneyB's answer for an answer that answers the question. I'm not sure how many ESL learners can handle the linguistics terminology, but this is the kind of approach that helps someone learn English. The dictionary entry for "nest" doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you're confused by the fact that *nest*, which you are likely to be familiar with as a noun, is used here as a verb.

As for how to identify the verb—by and large, it will be the first non-adverbial constituent after the subject. In this particular case, you parse the relative clause something like this:

> ... in which they nest

- You know immediately that the relativizer *which* is the object of the preposition *in*, because the preposition is right there in front of it. A preposition phrase is *very very* unlikely to act as subject of the clause; it *can't* be the verb; it is probably an ordinary locative indicating where something happens . . .
- . . . so the next constituent of the clause ought to be the subject. *They* is unambiguous here: it's a personal pronoun in subject form, so it has to be the subject of something, and it's a pretty safe assumption that what it's the subject of is the relative clause. Consequently  . . .
- . . . the next constituent should be the verb you're looking for. It might be preceded by an adverbial of some sort, so you have to be ready for that; but in this case a glance at what follows suggests that the relative clause actually ends after the next word, *nest*, so *nest* pretty much has to be the verb, despite the fact that you know it as a noun. You turn to your dictionary (I'll use [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nest) because it's on the top of my list of bookmarks) and Behold! you find as the second definition:

  > 2. <sup>verb</sup>
  >
  >    > When a bird **nests** somewhere, it builds a nest and settles there to lay its eggs.
  >    >
  >    > - *Some species may nest in close proximity to each other.*
  >    > - *...nesting sites*.

The same sort of analysis (but without the complication of dealing with a relative clause) will show that the verb in the main clause is *frequent* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/frequent) again):

> 2. verb
>
>    > If someone **frequents** a particular place, they regularly go there.
>    >     *[formal]*
>    >
>    > - *I hear he frequents the Cajun restaurant in Hampstead.*

Comment: +1 In the non-bolded part there's also *might, be, endeavoring* and *classify* as well as possibly the word *to*, of course :)